# Twitter Bootstrap 800px tablet media query issue?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media, tablet

I'm currently building a site with bootstraps responsive layout which I have working fine in my browser but for some reason when I view the same site on my Nexus 7 tablet (Screen 1200 x 800) in portrait format the site renders with the media query @media (max-width: 767px) instead of @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px).

Interestingly I checked this out on bootstraps [example sites][1] and exactly the same thing happens even though the screen size is big enough for the @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) media query.  The correct query is loaded when the tablet is in landscape format.

Here's bootstraps break points.

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Is there anything I can do to make sure the correct media query is picked up by the tablet?

Comment: did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue of what is being used to define the media query width vs. what you are calling screen width.

I found that calling the following javascript always matches up with the media query:

`window.innerWidth`

What does that show for your nexus 7?

See this for reference for discussion of viewport/media queries: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html